# Why is `poly` complaining about degree less than number of unique points?

Tags: r, polynomial-math

I am trying to generate orthogonal polynomials in R, but I keep getting an error I don't understand

```
> poly(1:1000, 50)
Error in poly(1:1000, 50) : 
  'degree' must be less than number of unique points
```

Surely the number of unique points is 1000?  What does it mean?  Is this a bug, and if so does anyone know I work around?

Edit:
This appears to kick in for degree > 27 for any number of points - is this an undocumented limit?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to generate a 50th order polynomial? I sincerely hope it is not for modeling...

Comment: No it's not for modelling, but now you put it like that, I'm feeling less surprised that it doesn't work for 50!  I was so engrossed in what I was doing I forgot about what most people probably use this function for.  (It's a bit complex to explain briefly, but it is to do with generating random analytic functions over an interval)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Numerical overflow. If you look at the code for `poly`, you'll see it's generating the individual polynomial terms as an intermediate step:

```
X <- outer(x, seq_len(n) - 1, "^")
```

and when `n` (the degree of the polynomial you want) is 50, the resulting terms go up to 1e132.

Comment: Great thanks - I can't complain, as Justin pointed out above, this isn't really the target usage for this function!