# step_poly error in tidymodels: "'degree' must be less than number of unique points"

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have seen several questions + answers for similar posts in SO ([ex. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850779/cannot-use-polyx-within-a-loop-degree-must-be-less-than-number-of-unique-po), [ex. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71131293/error-using-poly-degree-must-be-less-than-number-of-unique-points-while-usi), [ex. 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998919/why-is-poly-complaining-about-degree-less-than-number-of-unique-points)), but none seem to really address the problem in the context of `tidymodels`.

I am trying to use a second-order `step_poly` function inside a preprocessing recipe to prepare for a KNN model. The sample data is pulled from a [Kaggle Playground competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/playground-series-s3e11/overview). The training data itself is ~360,000 x 17 with all numeric predictors.

A light preprocessing reprex is:

```
rec <- recipe(cost ~ ., data = train) |> 
  update_role(id, new_role = 'id') |>
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())
  step_poly(all_predictors()) |> # this line fails??
  step_interact(~ all_predictors():all_predictors())
```

When going to prep the recipe, `prep(rec)`, an error is thrown:

**Error in poly(degree = 2L, x = c(0.871948016751444, 0.871948016751444,  : 'degree' must be less than number of unique points**

This also persists at tuning time. I understand the rationale behind *why* the polynomial degree must be less than the number of unique points, but I do not understand where the "unique points" are coming from. Why does my data only have a single unique point? And how can I fix this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in seeing that the problem comes from not having enough unique values in the columns you are trying to apply `step_poly()` to.

The default value of `degree` in `step_poly()` is 2, so it can only be apply to variables with at least 3 unique values.

We can use the function `n_distinct()` inside a map to find the number of distinct values for each variable.

```r
library(tidymodels)

train <- readr::read_csv("~/Desktop/train.csv.zip")
train <- janitor::clean_names(train)

train |> 
 select(where(is.numeric)) |>
 map_dbl(n_distinct) |>
  sort()
#>        recyclable_package                   low_fat                coffee_bar 
#>                         2                         2                         2 
#>               video_store                 salad_bar             prepared_food 
#>                         2                         2                         2 
#>                   florist avg_cars_at_home_approx_1    unit_sales_in_millions 
#>                         2                         5                         6 
#>            total_children      num_children_at_home                store_sqft 
#>                         6                         6                        20 
#>            units_per_case                      cost              gross_weight 
#>                        36                       328                       384 
#>   store_sales_in_millions                        id 
#>                      1044                    360336
```

We see a lot of them just have 2 values, so you will have to manually specify which variables to have it applied to

```r
rec <- recipe(cost ~ ., data = train) |> 
  update_role(id, new_role = 'id') |>
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) |>
  step_poly(cost, gross_weight, store_sales_in_millions) |>
  step_interact(~ all_predictors():all_predictors())

rec |>
  prep()
#> 
#> ── Recipe ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> ── Inputs 
#> Number of variables by role
#> outcome:    1
#> predictor: 15
#> id:         1
#> 
#> ── Training information 
#> Training data contained 360336 data points and no incomplete rows.
#> 
#> ── Operations 
#> • Centering and scaling for: store_sales_in_millions, ... | Trained
#> • Orthogonal polynomials on: cost, gross_weight, ... | Trained
#> • Interactions with: (unit_sales_in_millions + total_children +
#>   num_children_at_home + avg_cars_at_home_approx_1 + recyclable_package +
#>   low_fat + units_per_case + store_sqft + coffee_bar + video_store + salad_bar
#>   + prepared_food + florist + cost_poly_1 + cost_poly_2 + gross_weight_poly_1 +
#>   gross_weight_poly_2 + store_sales_in_millions_poly_1 +
#>   store_sales_in_millions_poly_2):(unit_sales_in_millions + total_children +
#>   num_children_at_home + avg_cars_at_home_approx_1 + recyclable_package +
#>   low_fat + units_per_case + store_sqft + coffee_bar + video_store + salad_bar
#>   + prepared_food + florist + cost_poly_1 + cost_poly_2 + gross_weight_poly_1 +
#>   gross_weight_poly_2 + store_sales_in_millions_poly_1 +
#>   store_sales_in_millions_poly_2) | Trained
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>